# sql retrieval value in java is null

Tags: java, mysql

I inserted one column in sql with null value from java.while retrieving back it is not working with null.i also checked with string.length().But when i printed the value in System.out. the value is showing as null (just null).when i checked it with condition it is not entering into loop.

```
String id ="1234"; 
            String name="pratap";
            String gender=null;
            String email=null;
String service="GOOGLE";
        log.info(id+name+gender+email) //output is 1234pratapnullnull   

String insert = "INSERT INTO oauthuser VALUES('"+id+"','"+name+"','"+gender+"','"+email+"','"+service"')";
```

In the retrieval

```
query ="Select * FROM oauthuser where id="+"'"+id+"'";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  while(rs.next())
  {
 id=rs.getString(1);
 name=rs.getString(2);
 gender=rs.getString(3);
 email=rs.getString(4);
service_provider_name=rs.getString(5);
System.out.println(gender+email+name);//output is nullnullpratap

  } 

if(gender!="male" && gender!="female")
 System.out.println("it is printing");
  if(gender==null)
      System.out.println("it is not printing");
con.close();
```

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: put the code of inserted and select

Comment: We cannot guess what is the problem until you show us how you implemented it

Comment: i will update my question with code.

Comment: try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802612/how-to-write-a-null-safe-compare-in-pure-sql
or show us the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try "null" instead of NULL , but better to show us the code

## after your update

remove + sign from your query like this

```
String id ="1234"; 
            String name="pratap";
            String gender="null";
            String email="null";
String service="GOOGLE";
        log.info(id+name+gender+email) //output is 1234pratapnullnull   

String insert = "INSERT INTO oauthuser VALUES('"id"','"name"','"gender"','"email"','"service"')"
```

and when you select , modify like this

```
if(gender.equals("null"))
      System.out.println("it is not printing");
```

Answer (score 2):

From your somewhat cryptic description of the problem I suspect that you may have inserted the string `"null"` rather than the SQL `NULL` value. The two are not the same (very different, in fact).

**edit** Having reviewed the code, this is exactly what happens. Take, for example, `gender`:

```
String gender = null;
...'"+gender+"',...
```

The above converts it to `'null'` (i.e. the SQL string `"null"`), and inserts that into the database.

My basic advice would be to read up on [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and use that instead of building the SQL query bit by bit as you're doing right now.

Finally, the following is broken:

```
if(gender!="male" && gender!="female")
```

This should be

```
if(!gender.equals("male") && !gender.equals("female"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your value is not null but "null" string? Start your application in debug, put break point and check it.