# MySQL not equals to isn't working

Tags: mysql

This is my code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT P_Id, Thing,Something Date
    FROM priv
    WHERE Something = '$thing' AND thing2 <> 'This'
    LIMIT 1"
) or die(mysql_error());
```

Code is working properly without `"thing2 <> 'this'"` statement, but when I implement `"thing2 <> 'this'"`, it returns 0 result. As if there were no empty rows in the table, but  there are empty (`NULL`) rows in the thing2 row of the table.

The problem is, that this "not equals" statement is not working, and I've tried everything, but it won't return any values with it.

edit(word of explanation):
Columns looks like this - P_Id | Something | Date | Thing1 | Thing 2 and i need to receive P_Id from a row where Something = Something AND Thing1 NOT EQLAS to 'this'(above example) and Thing2 ALSO NOT EQUALS to 'this'.I know it sounds crazy.Sorry

Ok, so i have tried some experiments, and it apears that "thing2 <>" thingy is not working on things1/thing2 columns, but other columns like "Something" table where are also 'this' entries it works properly(finding nerest row where there is not 'this' entry).But why this isn't working with things1 and 2???i have tried rename things column, but no result.

Comment: Can you include some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Sorry.But the query tell's it all(it is sample)

Comment: @user2107321: no, the question does **not** contain all the information. You *could* produce a small sample table, tell us the content and show us the result of a test query. That's called a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (be sure to follow and read that link!) and it's a *very good idea* both for finding the problem yourself *and* for being able to communicate the problem concisely.

Comment: table looks like this - P_Id | Something | Date | Thing1 | Thing 2 and i need to receive P_Id from a row where Something = Something AND Thing1 NOT EQLAS to 'this'(above example) and Thing2 ALSO NOT EQUALS to 'this'.I know it sounds cray.Sorry

Comment: Ok, did you look at the SSCCE site I linked to? Please do so again. 1.) create a **new** table that has some of the necessary columns. 2.) add *a few* rows, that look similar to the actual data (with some `NULL` and empty string values). 3.) try your query (in a modified form of course). 4.) **if** you manage to reproduce your problem, post **all** the information of steps #1-#3 here. 5.) if you *can't* reproduce it, find out what's the difference between the new toy table/query and the original one. Good luck.

Answer (score 9):

[`something <> NULL` will evaluate to `NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/working-with-null.html). And if used in a query that's pretty much the same as `0` (or `false`).

Remember that SQL uses [three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#SQL) and not simple binary logic.

You might need to check for NULL explicitly using `IS NULL`:

```
... OR THING IS NULL
```

Alernatively you can use the [NULL-safe equals operator `<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) with a negation (this is MySQL specific, however, [it's not standard SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802612/how-to-write-a-null-safe-compare-in-pure-sql)):

```
... AND NOT (THING <=> 'This')
```

Comment: To solve this, you can use the "[null-safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)" equals (`<=>`) and the `NOT` operator (as there is no "null-safe not equals").  `WHERE NOT (thing2 <=> 'this')`

Comment: @RocketHazmat: interesting, I didn't know that MySQL had such an operator. Mind if I add it to my answer?

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Go for it! :-)

Comment: <=> is not working it returns row where thing2  equals to 'This'

Comment: @user2107321: did you include the negation `NOT`?

Comment: Ok, get serious :) .I really don't know what is wrong with my query.What am i missing?

Comment: @user2107321: I **am** serious. What you're missing is a **clear and precise description of the problem you're seeing and of your input data**. You keep repeating us "it returns x" and "don't know what's wrong" and "what am I missing" when **you** are the only person with the necessary information to answer this question. **Either** provide us with **details** and create and post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org) **or** solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @user2107321: What does your query return?  What should it return?  What are some example rows from your table?

Comment: To Rocket: table looks like this - P_Id | Something | Date | Thing1 | Thing 2 and i need to receive P_Id from a row where Something = Something AND Thing1 NOT EQLAS to 'this'(above example) and Thing2 ALSO NOT EQUALS to 'this'.I know it sounds crazy.Sorry

Comment: @user2107321: that's not even close to an SSCCE. Also: you never even mentioned `Thing1` in your question above, how exactly where we suppsoed to *know* about that?

Comment: Ok, so i have tried some experiments, and it apears that "thing2 <>" thingy is not working on things1/thing2 columns, but other columns like "Something" table where are also 'this' entries it works properly(finding nerest row where there is not 'this' entry).But why this isn't working with things1 and 2???i have tried rename things column, but no result.

Comment: @user2107321: do you mean "rows" when you write "tables"? Because the only table you mention in your question is `priv`. Also: Friggin' create a SSCCE! Without that you will get no further input from me. (and edit it into your question, following the information in the comments is a mess).

Comment: OK, i've figured out what was causing trouble.It had something to do with NULL rows in thing1/thing2 columns i just filled it up with values and now it catches the right thing.Thank You for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I accept @JoachimSauer's way. Also, I prefer to try below one too.

````sql
... WHERE Something = '$thing' AND NOT (IFNULL(thing2,'') = 'This')
LIMIT 1```
````