# mysql select query can not fetch data with null value

Tags: mysql, null

[image]

In this table , if I make following query

```
select * from table where order_id != 1
```

I think, I am supposed to get row no 18 & 19. But instead, the query can't not fetch any row.

I can rewrite the query like this

```
select * from table where (order_id != 1 or order_id is null)
```

and it fetches the expected data, but should not the first query being able to fetch the row no `18 & 19`?

Comment: whats the datatype of  `order_id` in the table?

Comment: tinyint(4)   Null(Yes)   Default(NULL)

Comment: mate, this is one of the to-know things, feature wise, you should use `<>` instead of `!=` as its not a straight forward binary comaprison. check these 2 threads and you should be good to go with better understanding! :) [thread_1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501969/mysql-not-equals-to-isnt-working) , [thread_2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994408/query-not-equal-doesnt-work)

Comment: `select * from table where order_id <> 1` doesn't work also, no row is picked

Comment: `select * from table where order_id <> 1 or order_id is NULL` , your query will not consider `NULL` rows buddy! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`Docs`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html)

The `NULL` value can be surprising until you get used to it. Conceptually, NULL means “`a missing unknown value`” and it is treated somewhat differently from other values.

To test for `NULL`, use the `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` operators

You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as `=, <, or <>` to test for `NULL`.

Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with `NULL` is also `NULL`, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.

Comment: yep, very surprising :)

Comment: Very true "IS NULL" or "IS NOT NULL" worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Null is Null not an infinite number!

#### Solutions:

Set a default value for the *order_id*; Especially if it's a foreign key and it's supposed to join with other tables.

Using *IFNULL* function Alter your query to this:

```
select * from table where ifnull(order_id,-1) != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL operator `!=` or `<>` only works on values. `NULL` is not a value - it is just absence of value. 
Check this answer ,you might find this useful : 
[Not equal <> != operator on NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null)