# Postgresql and comparing to an empty field

Tags: postgresql, select, null, compare

It seems that in PostgreSQL, `empty_field != 1` (or some other value) is **FALSE**. If this is true, can somebody tell me how to compare with empty fields?

I have following query, which translates to "select all posts in users group for which one hasn't voted yet:

```
SELECT p.id, p.body, p.author_id, p.created_at
FROM posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN votes v ON v.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.group_id = 1 
AND v.user_id != 1
```

and it outputs nothing, even though **votes** table is empty. Maybe there is something wrong with my query and not with the logic above?

**Edit:** it seems that changing `v.user_id != 1`, to `v.user_id IS DISTINCT FROM 1`, did the job.
From PostgreSQL docs:

> For non-null inputs, IS DISTINCT FROM
>   is the same as the <> operator.
>   However, when both inputs are null it
>   will return false, and when just one
>   input is null it will return true.

Comment: Possible duplicate with various other questions, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/1833949/141081, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3777230/141081, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to return rows where v.user_id is NULL then you need to handle that specially. One way you can fix it is to write:

```
AND COALESCE(v.user_id, 0) != 1
```

Another option is:

```
AND (v.user_id != 1 OR v.user_id IS NULL)
```

*Edit*: spacemonkey is correct that in PostgreSQL you should use `IS DISTINCT FROM` here.

Comment: it seems that IS DISTINCT FROM did the job too

Comment: @spacemonkey: You're right. That's actually a better way to do it in PostgreSQL. I completely overlooked it.

Answer (score 2):

NULL is a unknown value so it can never equal something.  Look into using the COALESCE function.