# Why in SQL NULL can't match with NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, null

I'm new to SQL concepts, while studying NULL expression I wonder why NULL can't match with NULL can anyone tell me a real world example to simply this concept?

Comment: .... `is null`?

Comment: Yup. Something funny: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2746 :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar, You can check that something is null. But not compare because the result is uknown, something like dividing by zero.

Comment: Even worse, `"bla" != NULL` is false, even if that NULL is from another column.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Rule : Not even a NULL can be equal to NULL.

A Non-Technical aspect

If you ask two girls, how old they are? may be you would hear them to refuse to answer your question,
   Both girls are giving you NULL as age and this doesn't mean both have similar age.
   So there is nothing can be equal to null.

Comment: @JoeNorman Glad to help you but consider reading answers by Damien and others, they list the technical aspect.

Comment: @JoeGJoseph thanks dude.. well actually a day before i asked similar kinda question to a lady in my office and she refused to answer on her birthday. :P

Comment: the way it makes sense in my head:  null is a state... not a value. and a value cannot equal a state of being.

Answer (score 17):

`NULL` indicates an *absence* of a value. The designers of SQL decided that it made sense that, when asked whether `A` (for which we do not know its value) and `B` (for which we do not know its value) are equal, the answer must be `UNKNOWN` - they might be equal, they might not be. We do not have adequate information to decide either way.

You might want to read up on [Three valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) - the possible results of any comparison in SQL are `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `UNKNOWN` (mysql treats `UNKNOWN` and `NULL` as synonymous. Not all RDBMSs do)

Answer (score 4):

`NULL` is an unknown value. Therefore it makes little sense to judge `NULL == NULL`. That's like asking "is this unknown value equal to that unknown value" - no clue..

See [why is null not equal to null false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833949/why-is-null-not-equal-to-null-false) for a possibly better explaination

Answer (score 4):

NULL is the absence of data in a field.

You can check NULL values with IS NULL

See [IS NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null)

```
mysql> SELECT NULL IS NULL;
+--------------+
| NULL IS NULL |
+--------------+
|            1 |
+--------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make a comparison where NULL does indeed equal NULL, you can use a pair of `coalesce` methods with a *special* default value.  The easiest example is on a nullable string column.

```
coalesce(MiddleName,'')=coalesce(@MiddleName,'')
```

This comparison returns true if @MiddleName variable has a null value and the MiddleName column also has a null value.  Of course, it also matches empty strings too.  If that is an issue, you could change the special value to something silly, like

```
coalesce(MiddleName,'<NULL_DEFAULT>')=coalesce(@MiddleName,'<NULL_DEFAULT>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **=** for NULL instead you can use **IS NULL**

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please folllow the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-null.html)

The `NULL` value is never true in comparison to any other value, even `NULL`.

To check we can use

```
Is Null or Not Null operators ..
```

[Document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Correct me if 'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

In SQL the WHERE clause only includes the value if the result of the expression is equal to TRUE. (This is not the same as "if the result of the expression is not FALSE")

Any binary operation in SQL that has NULL on one side evaluates to NULL (think of NULL as being a synonym for unknown)

so

```
Select ... Where null = null

Select ... Where field = null

Select ... Where null = field
```

Will all return no rows as in each case the where class evaluates to NULL which is not TRUE

Answer (score 0):

Actually NULL means UNKNOWN value So how we compare two UNKNOWN values.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `IS NULL`, another way to match NULL in *SQL Server*, is the function `ISNULL`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A t1
INNER JOIN TABLE_B t2 ON ISNULL(t1.somecol, somevalue) = ISNULL(t2.somecol, somevalue)
```

where *somevalue* could be 'NULL' or 0 or whatever.