# mysqli query always returning only 1 row

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to figure out why the `num_rows` always return `1`? I searched high and low to find out what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be grateful! In my query where I have `status = ''` that should find the rows where `status` is `NULL` correct? If so then the count should be `2`.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM referrals WHERE (status = 'W' OR status = '') AND referral_id = '".$thisId."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$TotalRcount = $result->num_rows;
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
   //read columns
}

$inprogress =      $TotalRcount;
echo $TotalRcount; // Always returning 1
```

Comment: Why would a "NULL" row be returned. Can you show the contents of a simple database that gives you this problem? Without knowing what is in your DB it's hard to comment...

Comment: Basically the column `status` in each `row` may have `NULL` if it has not been set yet. Make since? I updated my question to make better since :)

Comment: Nothing matches NULL. See this earlier question / answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853944/why-in-sql-null-cant-match-with-null

Comment: [`mysqli_result::$num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) "returns number of rows in the result set." If you are getting `1` returned, then there is `1 result`.

Comment: Thanks Floris! Please submit your answer and I will accept it. I did not know that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your status field may be empty, or it may have a zero-length string in it. They are not the same.

Try 
    (status = 'W' or status  <= '')

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to test for a null with [`IS NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/is-null-optimization.html)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM referrals WHERE (status = 'W' OR status = '' OR status is null) AND referral_id = '".$thisId."'";
```

While you can't test for equality of null you can test to see if a field is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$TotalRcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```