# Selecting rows which are not null in sql

Tags: sql

Why doesn't the following code work in SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM DATA
WHERE VALUE != NULL;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we can not Compare null value with **=** We Special operator to compare null
value in sql
**IS OPERATOR**

```
SELECT * 
FROM DATA
WHERE VALUE is not NULL;
```

Null is not any Value.Sql consider  Null as **Unknown/absence of data**.

Answer (score 2):

The condition you written is not in proper format.
If you want to select not null values from your table then you can use the following command

```
select *from table name where column name IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If should work if you replace "!=" with "IS NOT".

Comment: NULL is a special case, nothing is equal to NULL. NULLs are not picked out by this either, despite not being 1 or 2: `VALUE NOT IN (1,2)`.

Comment: They way I conceptualize it, NULL is the absence of data. Using an equality comparer between data and the absence of data it a logical non-starter. Check out this similar question for another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853944/why-in-sql-null-cant-match-with-null

Answer (score 1):

The code will not work in SQL because it is not possible to test for NULL values with the following operators =, <, or <>. It is not possible to compare NULL and 0 as they are not equivalent.

You can test for NULL values using the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators instead.

```
SELECT * 
FROM DATA
WHERE VALUE IS NOT NULL
```

[http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Because a NULL value indicates an absence of data, it doesn't make sense to compare something with a value to it with an equals operator.

You can make your SELECT statement work by setting ANSI_NULLS OFF

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

before running the statement. You can get further information here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

Comment: Note that this is a MS SQL Server specific feature. (And no DBMS specified...)

Answer (score 0):

Null does not contain any value. Null is neither zero nor any value.
So we can't compare it using comparison operators.
Instead of using '=', you should use 'IS' keyword.

```
SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE VALUE IS NOT NULL;
```