# oracle sql filter for nullable values

Tags: sql, oracle

Is that expected behavior for oracle 11g. Can someone explain why last query does not include null value?

```
table

statuscode
13
null
---------------------------------------------------------
select count(*) from table -- returns 2
select count(*) from table where statuscode = 13 --returns 1
select count(*) from table where statuscode <> 13 --returns 0
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior.  That is how `NULL` values work -- all comparisons other than `is null` return the equivalent of false.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853944/why-in-sql-null-cant-match-with-null

Comment: I tested it was working with "is null" but didnt know the reason. thanks.

Comment: @FlorinGhita I searched it for long time but couldn't find the right google query to match the question. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I've search on stackoverflow "SQL NULL" :)

Comment: I wrote this "counting null values in sql" on google but no luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of `NULL` as an unknown value and testing if something equals (or does not equal) an unknown will result in an unknown (`NULL`) as the answer. The SQL query will display results when the boolean filter is `TRUE` and this will not be the case if one value is `NULL`.

You can test the logic in PL/SQL (since it has an accessible `BOOLEAN` type):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  FUNCTION bool_to_string( bool BOOLEAN ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  AS
  BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN bool IS NULL  THEN 'NULL'
                WHEN bool =  TRUE  THEN 'TRUE'
                WHEN bool =  FALSE THEN 'FALSE'
                ELSE                    'ERROR' END;
  END;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'A =  A    => ' || bool_to_string( 'A' = 'A' ) );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'A <> A    => ' || bool_to_string( 'A' <> 'A' ) );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'A =  NULL => ' || bool_to_string( 'A' = NULL ) );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'A <> NULL => ' || bool_to_string( 'A' <> NULL ) );
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

```
A =  A    => TRUE
A <> A    => FALSE
A =  NULL => NULL
A <> NULL => NULL
```

Note that the last two tests do not return `FALSE` but return `NULL`.

If you want to count including `NULL`s then you can do:

```
select count(*) from table where statuscode <> 13 OR statuscode IS NULL
```