# SQL hide result if all three fields are 'Yes'

Tags: php, mysql

I a have a MySQL db with 4 fields:

```
id | planchanged | dataremoved | rolloverenabled |
1  | Yes         | Yes         | Yes             |
2  | NULL        |             |                 |
3  |             | Yes         |                 |
4  | Yes         |             | Yes             |
5  |             |             | NULL            |
```

How do I query this db to show only records that doesn't have all 'Yes' on those three fields. Please also take into consideration that some of thos fields might be *Null*. So based on that example my result should show records 2,3,4 and 5.

Comment: "Please also take into consideration that some of thos fields might be Null" --- looks like a job description. Have you tried to solve your task yourself?

Comment: yes I did but I can only get the result to show when all three are blank and any Null records are not coming up. Not sure what you mean by job description though.

Comment: And just for fun - the most straightforward condition that doesn't need to take `NULL` behaviour into account is: `NOT (planchanged = 'Yes' AND dataremoved = 'Yes' AND rolloverenabled = 'Yes')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTableName 
WHERE planchanged IS NULL OR planchanged <> 'Yes' 
OR dataremoved IS NULL OR dataremoved <> 'Yes' 
OR rolloverenabled IS NULL OR rolloverenabled <> 'Yes'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fdf4/2)

Comment: Aren't these redundant: planchanged IS NULL OR planchanged <> 'Yes'

Comment: @Boundless: `NULL` never matches to anything. So `NULL = 'Yes'` == false, and `NULL <> 'Yes'` == false

Comment: @Boundless Unfortunately, not for mysql (and most others depending on NULL matching settings). See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fdf4/3

Comment: Thank you for the reply and all the comments I certainly learned some new stuff about NULL

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
SELECT * FROM TableName 
WHERE coalesce(planchanged,'-') <> 'Yes' OR 
coalesce(dataremoved,'-') <> 'Yes' OR
coalesce(rolloverenabled,'-') <>'Yes'
```

SQL [FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fb95/3)

Comment: If 2 columns are yes, and a 3rd isn't yes he wants it to show

Comment: Just replace `AND` with `OR`

Comment: Be aware that using coalesce in the where clause will stop the use of any indexes on those columns

Comment: @lc. Thank you, I was not aware of that. In that case your answer should work for OP. I'll leave my answer as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  yourTableName 
WHERE planchanged IS NULL 
  OR  dataremoved IS NULL 
  OR  rolloverenabled IS NULL 
  OR  planchanged <> 'Yes' 
  OR  dataremoved <> 'Yes' 
  OR  rolloverenabled <> 'Yes'
```

Comment: "..show only records that doesn't have all 'Yes'..." shouldn't those OR's be AND's?

Comment: no, they shouldn't. The query is correct.  Please read the question.

Comment: Great, I added is null check to the query.  I didn't know that 'yes' <> NULL was false

Comment: Yep, because `null` is not equal to anything. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833949/why-is-null-not-equal-to-null-false

Comment: It's funny that it's not equal to anything, yet it's not not equal either.

Comment: Yeah, I remember thinking it was strange at first. But when you consider that `null` basically means "we do not know what the value is", there is no way to know what it does (or does *not*) equal.