# Using ISNULL in where Clause doesn't return records with NULL field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, isnull

**Table:**

```
ID     AppType     AppSubType   Factor
1   SC  CD      1.0000000000
2   SC  CD      2.0000000000
3   SC  NULL    3.0000000000
4   SC  NULL    4.0000000000
```

**Query:**

```
declare @ast varchar(10)

set @ast = null

select *
from tbl
where AppType = 'SC' and AppSubType = ISNULL(@ast, AppSubType)
```

**Result:**

```
ID  AppType AppSubType  Factor
1   SC  CD  1.0000000000
2   SC  CD  2.0000000000
```

**Question:**

Shouldn't this query return all 4 records and not just the first 2?

Comment: Looks like SQL. Please add a tag for that. And whilst you're editing tags, please add an appropriate one for whichever database system you're using (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc)

Comment: Also - what are you trying to do? Is it one or both of: a) return all rows that match `@ast` or that have a `NULL`, or b) if `@ast` is `NULL`, return rows with a `NULL`. Specifically, what's the expected behaviour when `@ast` *isn't* `NULL`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is null not equal to null false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833949/why-is-null-not-equal-to-null-false) (well, close enough).

Comment: The query is in a stored procedure.  What i wanted was if i don't pass the AppSubType parameter(passed as null), it should return all 4 records(it's like not to consider AppSubType in the where condition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abviously @ast is null and Isnull would exchange null with other value, so you shouldn't expect @ast to be not null. If your AppSubType is null , so the result become null but `AppSubType=null` doesn't mean because `AppSubType is null` is true. Because null is not a value so it cant work with equal.
for your expected result this code will work.

```
declare @ast varchar(10)

set @ast = null

select *
from tbl
where AppType = 'SC' and (AppSubType = ISNULL(@ast, AppSubType) Or AppSubType is null)
```

Comment: thanx amirreza, this approach works and simple. But just to be clear, why would it not return last 2 records using the original query?

ex.

When @ast is passed as null, the condition AppSubType = ISNULL(@ast, AppSubType) becomes AppSubType = AppSubType

Comment: @user1842048 - The answer hints at why, but it could potentially be made more clear.  However, note that this version returns all rows where `AppSubType` is null regardless of what `@ast` is...

Comment: Look , When @ast is passed as null, the condition AppSubType = ISNULL(@ast, AppSubType) becomes AppSubType = AppSubType , the query uses rows at the time , so it becomes AppSubType =null this not mean than AppSubType is null this is just a nonsense comparison so the last 2 rows which are null are not returned.

Comment: @AmirrezaKeshavarz - It's note necessarily a 'nonsense comparison'; most computer languages will return true for a `null == null` comparison.  If the OP has background in one of those languages, the way SQL functions may come as a surprise (especially given he's comparing the same column...)

Comment: Sql at first was Sequel Stand for english structured query language, and then changes to sql ,it is very near to english language. also null is not a value , it is just a symbol for a missing value. so = can't operate on it tsql has a structure for this comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a case condition in where clause as:

```
declare @ast varchar(10)

set @ast = null

select *
from tbl
where AppType = 'SC' and 1=
      case when isnull(@ast ,'') = '' and isnull(AppSubType ,'') = '' then 1
           when AppSubType = ISNULL(@ast, AppSubType) then 1 
           else 0
      end
```

Comment: ... there's a language feature that would really help here.  Namely, the `<column name> IS NULL` check.  And what's with the `CASE` statement instead of just using Boolean logic?

Answer (score 0):

Please understand the behavior of ISNULL explained in below blog.

the very first expression in the isnull function is a column value or the expression of some result.

[ISNULL Explored in Detail](http://borngeek.in/isnulltransact-sql-explored-in-detail/)

The code looks like a search functionality. If the value is not given then replace them with whatever is there in database and if given pull only those records which are matched.