# conditional active record query with rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller, rails-activerecord

By default :completed_at is nil. If I use the complete method then completed_at turns into Time.now. I checked it and it worked fine. 
In despite of this my query is not working in the case of the incoming/outgoing tasks. What is really weird that the query works perfectly with the completed tasks. So "where" query doesn't work, but "where.not" does. Can you help me out with this?

```
def incoming_tasks
  @user =current_user
  @executed_tasks = @user.executed_tasks.where("completed_at = ?", 'nil').order("created_at DESC")
end

def outgoing_tasks
  @user = current_user
  @assigned_tasks = @user.assigned_tasks.where("completed_at = ?", 'nil').order("created_at DESC")
end

def completed_tasks
  @user = current_user
  @assigned_tasks = @user.assigned_tasks.where.not("completed_at = ?", 'nil').order("completed_at DESC")
  @executed_tasks = @user.executed_tasks.where.not("completed_at = ?", 'nil').order("completed_at DESC")
end
```

Here is how I made the completed_at attribute having a date:

```
def complete
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  @task.update_attribute(:completed_at, Time.now)
  redirect_to completed_tasks_user_tasks_path(current_user)
end
```

Comment: SQL usually uses the keyword `IS` to determine if a value is null, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833949/why-is-null-not-equal-to-null-false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented above, you need to generate SQL with the `IS` keyword to determine if a column is `NULL`. Rather than wrangle this yourself, you can pass a hash to `where` and let ActiveRecord handle the subtleties; i.e:

```
def incoming_tasks
  @user =current_user
  @executed_tasks = @user.executed_tasks.where(completed_at: nil).order("created_at DESC")
end

def outgoing_tasks
  @user = current_user
  @assigned_tasks = @user.assigned_tasks.where(completed_at: nil).order("created_at DESC")
end

def completed_tasks
  @user = current_user
  @assigned_tasks = @user.assigned_tasks.where.not(completed_at: nil).order("completed_at DESC")
  @executed_tasks = @user.executed_tasks.where.not(completed_at: nil).order("completed_at DESC")
end
```

As an aside, this would be a great place to use a scope.

**Edit for detail:**

(Caveat: SQL is a spec, not an implementation, and the SQL generated by rails depends on the database adapter. The following may vary depending on your choice of database.)

Ok, a few things:

1. You're using `where("completed_at = ?", 'nil')`, which is actually looking for records where `completed_at` is the **string** `"nil"`. This is almost certainly not what you want, and has other unintended consequences.
2. SQL has a very particular way of handling `NULL` values when it comes to matching rows. When using the `=` operator in a `WHERE` clause, it will ignore rows with `NULL` values. You must use one of the `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` operators to reason about `NULL` values.

Consider the table:

```
| id | completed_at               |

| 1  | 2015-07-11 23:23:19.259576 |
| 2  | NULL                       |
```

With the following queries:

```
Rails                                | SQL                                | Result

where("completed_at = ?", 'nil')     | WHERE (completed_at = 'nil')       | nothing, since completed_at isn't even a string
where.not("completed_at = ?", 'nil') | WHERE (NOT (completed_at = 'nil')) | only row 1, since = can't match a NULL value, even when negated
where("completed_at = ?", nil)       | WHERE (completed_at = NULL)        | nothing, you can't test for NULL with the = operator
where.not("completed_at = ?", nil)   | WHERE (NOT (completed_at = NULL))  | nothing, you can't test for not NULL with = either
where(completed_at: nil)             | WHERE completed_at IS NULL         | row 2 only
where.not(completed_at: nil)         | WHERE (completed_at IS NOT NULL)   | row 1 only
```

Of course, `where(completed_at: nil)` is just shorthand for `where('completed_at IS NULL')`, and the same for its converse, but the hash format is more idiomatic and independent of the database adapter.

The magic part of all this is that ActiveRecord is able to figure out if it should use `=` or `IS NULL` by looking at the hash you pass to `where`. If you pass a fragment, it has no idea, so it applies it blindly.

Comment: Can you tell me why it worked with where.not and why not with where? I will try to use the scope. If I get stuck with it I will ask you how it should be done. Thx

Comment: Thanks for the insight. This table made it totally clear.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer if you're satisfied.

Comment: ahmacleod ,I've got an other question connected to this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613117/rails-active-record-query-for-2-attributes-listed-together . Could you take a look at it? Based on your previous answer I guess this is pretty easy for you. Main problem that I don't know how the different methods (that are already defined) can be chained together. I made a scope of this "completed" query, that you wrote, then I couldn't chain to those that the guys recommended for the question I just linked. I've spent around 10hours on this and couldn't figure it out. Thanks in advance!