# rails active record query for 2 attributes listed together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, model-view-controller, rails-activerecord

I'd like create an index task site and wanna list all the tasks (incoming called executed_tasks in the model and outgoing called assigned_tasks in the model) in the same list, mixed based on created_at. With the following code I can create 2 separate lists under each other for incoming and outgoing tasks, but doesn't look nice. I'm not even sure if I should make some changes in the model, the controller or the view.

task.rb

```
belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :executor, class_name: "User"
```

user.rb

```
has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "assigner_id"
has_many :executed_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "executor_id"
```

tasks.controller.rb

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @assigned_tasks = @user.assigned_tasks.order("created_at DESC")
  @executed_tasks = @user.executed_tasks.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

tasks/index.html.erb

```
<div class= "container">
  <div class = "row">
    <% @assigned_tasks.each do |task| %>
      <% unless task.completed? %>
        <%= link_to user_task_path(id: task.id) do %> 
          <%= task.name %> 
        <% end %> 
        <%= task.content %>
        <%= task.executor.profile.first_name %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <br />
    <br />
    <% @executed_tasks.each do |task| %>
      <% unless task.completed? %>
        <%= link_to user_task_path(id: task.id) do %>
          <%= task.name %>
        <% end %>
        <%= task.content %>
        <%= task.assigner.profile.first_name %>
      <% end %> 
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method in your User model which will return the combined results from both the scope (assigned_tasks and excuted_tasks).

User.rb

```
  def tasks 
    tasks = assigned_tasks.uncompleted.order("created_at DESC")
    tasks += executed_tasks.uncompleted.order("created_at DESC")
    tasks.sort_by { |h| h[:created_at] }.reverse!
  end
```

tasks.controller.rb

```
def index
  @user = current_user
end
```

view

```
<% @user.tasks.each do |task| %>
  ..
  ..
<% end %>
```

Comment: I got tihs error message: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: can you check and say if current_user is nil ? ..share more information

Comment: I can't check it in irb since I'm using current_user, but I have the before_action: authenticate_user! in my tasks_controller for all the actions and works perfectly. So I'm sure I'm logged in, so current_user is not nil.

Comment: What's really weird for me that if I use the console I can easily call user.tasks, which shows all the tasks including assigned and executed tasks as well.

Comment: This should work easily,, share ur existing code so I can take a look too :)

Comment: Dave I am not sure which part is necessary to figure this out, so I share the github repo: https://github.com/faskyn/faskyn . If u need something else, just let me know.

Comment: **Dave I am not sure which part is necessary to figure this out, so I share the github repo: https://github.com/faskyn/faskyn . If u need something else, just let me know. As a note: Paul's answer works, but I can't chain his def tasks method with my scopes in my index action. These scopes are for checking if the tasks are completed and can be found in my task.rb: (scope :completed, -> { where.not(completed_at: nil) }; scope :uncompleted, -> { where(completed_at: nil) }.

Comment: Updated answer.. Let me know on this :)

Comment: Seems to be working :). Dave, can you explain me in simple terms, what's the difference compared to the previous solution and why the controller is not needed for this action? And let me ask one last question. Is this solution good when it comes to performance and speed? Thx a lot! I really appreciate that you spend so much time on this.

Comment: This is the same solution and previously it was not working because we  passed nil instance variables( @assigned_tasks &  @ executed_tasks) in array.  Regarding controller, this code can be written in controller also but respecting the rails best practice (Fat model Skinny Controller), I moved this code into model. This solution is good in terms of all because we are not doing any heavy processing, it will just query database based on scope and will return the combined results  :) adding paginate will make things easier for huge records in DB.

Comment: Dave, how can you make this paginate? I mean I would use will_paginate gem but its code must be added in the controller and I have nothing there at the moment. :)

Comment: Using will_paginate. Add in ur controller,.. @ tasks = @user.tasks.paginate(params[:page]) and use @tasks.each ... in your view

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a combined query method on `User` that returns a relation. That way you can tack on additional scopes, or merge into a join.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "assigner_id"
  has_many :executed_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "executor_id"

  def associated_tasks
    Task.where('tasks.assigner_id = ? OR tasks.executer_id = ?', id, id)
  end
end

user = User.first
tasks = user.associated_tasks
```

Alternatively, you could create a scope on `Task`:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :executor, class_name: "User"
  scope :associated_with_user, (u) -> { where('tasks.assigner_id = ? OR tasks.executer_id = ?', u.id, u.id) }
end

user = User.first
tasks = Task.associated_with_user(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array from assigned and executed tasks and sort them by created_at.
Something like that:

```
tasks = []
tasks << @assigned_tasks
tasks << @expired_tasks
@tasks = tasks.sort_by { |c| c[:created_at]}.reverse
```

and in your view:

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add a method to the user model.

user.rb

```
def tasks
  Task.find_by_sql ["SELECT tasks.* FROM tasks WHERE  assigner_id = ? OR executor_id = ? order by created_at DESC", self.id, self.id]
end
```

Your controller could look like this:

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @all_tasks = @user.tasks
  @assigned_tasks = @user.assigned_tasks.order("created_at DESC")
  @executed_tasks = @user.executed_tasks.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Then you can call user.tasks in your view and the database can take care of retrieving and sorting the records...

*the above syntax isn't fully tested but hopefully will give you something to work with.*

Comment: How would my controller would look like? I also wanna add pagination later with gem. Pagination must be set in controller as well, I hope this method will be compatible with that.

Comment: I tried it and got this: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I tried it again and it's working, but I need something more as I would like to check if the task is uncompleted or not. I use scope for that and works this way: 
    @executed_tasks =@user.executed_tasks.uncompleted.order("created_at DESC")