# Why does the SQL language use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL instead of = NULL or <> NULL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I mostly have application development background. In programming languages `variable == null` or `variable != null` works.

When it comes to SQL, below queries don't give any syntax errors but don't return correct results either.

```
select SomeColumn from SomeTable where SomeNullableColumn=null
select SomeColumn from SomeTable where SomeNullableColumn<>null
```

Why do we need to write the queries with `is null` or `is not null` to get correct results?

```
select SomeColumn from SomeTable where SomeNullableColumn is null
select SomeColumn from SomeTable where SomeNullableColumn is not null
```

What's the reasons/requirements behind `is null` or `is not null` instead of `=null` or `<>null`?

Is this ANSI SQL or Microsoft's TSQL standard?

Comment: Because `NULL` is not a value, it means there is no value. You can't compare something with nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is null not equal to null false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833949/why-is-null-not-equal-to-null-false)

Comment: yup duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `null` is not equal to `null`, like `NaN` ("not a number" produced when, for example, 0 is divided by 0 or raised to the power of 0) is not equal to `NaN`. Consider `null` as an unknown value (an unknown value is not necessarily equal to some unknown value).

Answer (score 2):

Because sql is based on set theory and predicate logic. This two strong mathematical foundations contains mathematical logic - `Boolean algebra`. In this logic exist three values - `TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN (=NULL)`.

`Is null` is used instead of `= null` to separate logic. And why it is in ANSI standard? It is to make it more readable and separate three-valued logic.

In common datawarehouses is null replaced by '' to make qry more simple.

Or try `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` option.