# Comparing nulls in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, null

Is there a nicer way of comparing if two values are equal if they can be nulls other than the following?

```
a = b or (a is null and b is null)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get null == null in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191640/get-null-null-in-sql). Note that in general, while there are simpler ways to write this, it is likely the most efficient way, because there are no function references.

Comment: I'm curious if that's true, just because `is null` doesn't have parentheses, does not mean functions aren't called; after all, comparisons are still performed.  I'd bet that the db has been optimized for `coalesce`, since it is used frequently.  I'm not saying you're wrong, just that it'd be interesting to benchmark it with the newer db engines.

Comment: Just tested it on an 11g instance. While not as dramatic, the coalesce uses about 10% more CPU.

Comment: ty, DCookie, that's good general information.  If anyone could do the same analysis with: How many tuples - fields, records, tables? What's the difference in table size? What was the difference in speed?  Just curious.

Answer (score 5):

You can:

```
a=b or coalesce(a,b) is null
```

You could also use `nvl`, but that is a legacy function and `coalesce` is quicker, since it stops at the first non-null

Comment: This answer is misleading: `nvl` and `coalesce` perform equivalently in most uses (passed two columns or a column and a static value). It's only when the second parameter is a function or a complex evaluation (and the first parameter is null) that `coalesce` performs better.

Comment: Well I think `nvl` only accepts two arguments, whereas `coalesce` will accept a list, so yes, you are correct.  The other thing to note is that I believe `nvl` does not require strict datatypes, whereas `coalesce` requires all the datatypes to be the same - there could be some performance implications there.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DECODE(A,B,1) = 1`

DECODE is irregular in its treatment of NULLs.

However I think the intention is unclear and prefer vol7ron's answer. Clarity over minimising typing !

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it with nvl and set it to some value not expected in your set:

```
NVL(a,0) = NVL(b,0)
```

Comment: Different results if A is 0 and B is null.

Comment: I think haitek implied that `0` was the value not expected in the set.  I think this is a good example of where it's important to keep SQL comments w/ the code.  It's valid, but important for the programmer/maintainer to be aware of the field's possible values; which is probably the very reason I'd shy away from it