# SQL NULL Condition

Tags: sql

I'm new to development. In sql I have written a stored procedure and
it is working correctly but I just wanted to make sure it is done the correct way.

Here I am using an IF statement in sp to check whether date column in a table is NULL or not:

```
  if ((select sdate 
       from tbla 
         where id='3') = Null)
begin
  some query
end
```

Will this work for all cases or do I need to check for ''(empty) also?

Comment: Depends on your database - some databases treat "empty" and `NULL` as equivalent - others don't. So to get a decent answer for your situation, we need to know **database system** and its version that you're using. "SQL" is just that - the structured query language - that's **not** a database system .....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get null == null in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191640/get-null-null-in-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empty and NULL are not the same thing, so you will need to check for an empty string separately. You also should use `is null` rather than `= null` to check if a column is null.

Answer (score 11):

In SQL null is not equal to anything, including other nulls. You need to use `is null` instead of the `=` operation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display some other expression whenever something is null, Coalesce may be what you want.

`Select CASE When (null = null) Then 1 Else 0 END`

Result: 0

`Select CASE When (null is null) Then 1 Else 0 END`

Result: 1

`Select null + 'soemthing'`

Result: null

`Select Coalesce(null, 'DefaultValueIfNull')`

Result: DefaultValueIfNull

Append a space and last name only if lastname is not null:

`select FirstName + coalesce(' ' + LastName, '') From People`

Append a space and last name only if lastname is not null, with handling for empty LastName:

`select FirstName + coalesce(' ' + CASE LastName When '' Then null Else LastName END, '') From People`