# What is the Query to filter the rows without Data(null)

Tags: mysql

Is this correct if I want to filter the employee name which their leave column is null in Leaves table.....if it's not would you help me?

```
Select name from Leave where leave!=null;
```

Comment: NULLs are a special case - use `leave IS NOT NULL`. This has already been asked [thousands of times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+null), so make sure to search for an answer before posting questions. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL NULL Condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361372/sql-null-condition)

Comment: thanks alot......!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `IS NOT NULL`

```
 SELECT name FROM Leave WHERE leave IS NOT NULL;
```