# oracle sql - how to get columns which contain string or null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with 3 columns:

[image]

I want to get all records `where type like '%' and is_connect like 'N'`, Including rows where type `IS NULL` or contains a string.

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OFFER 
WHERE TYPE LIKE '%' 
AND IS_CONNECT LIKE 'N';
```

I got the rows where type is `NOT NULL`, but how can I get all rows, even when the type `IS NULL`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get null == null in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191640/get-null-null-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all or the rows where there is either a value or no value, simply exclude the field from your `where` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM OFFER WHERE IS_CONNECT = 'N';
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove the like clause if you want all the entries for type :

```
SELECT * FROM OFFER WHERE (TYPE LIKE '%'  or TYPE is NULL) AND IS_CONNECT = 'N';
```

Comment: This is probably a better solution than mine..I would probably go with this... Since you are really not doing anything special with a check like `TYPE LIKE '%'`

Comment: i can't remov like clause , i need to filter table with type and is_connect columns

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Where N is you first alphabet. 
SELECT * FROM OFFER 
WHERE TYPE is null 
AND IS_CONNECT LIKE 'N%';

Where N is the last alphabet in your type. 
SELECT * FROM OFFER 
WHERE TYPE is null 
AND IS_CONNECT LIKE '%N';
```

__
BCG14

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there..Just use an OR condition to include null check...Also, you didnt have a 'N%' after is_connect like

```
SELECT * FROM OFFER WHERE (TYPE LIKE '%'  or TYPE is NULL) AND IS_CONNECT LIKE 'N%'
```